# java type generic: why Function<? super E, ? extends F> is more preferred than Function<E, F>?

Tags: java, generics

There is class called Foo as following:

```
public class Foo<E> {

    private List<E> ls;

    public Foo(List<E> ls) {
        this.ls = ls;
    }

    public void add(E l) {
        this.ls.add(l);
    }

    public <F> Foo<F> map(Function<? super E, ? extends F> f) {
        Foo<F> res = new Foo<F>(new ArrayList<F>());
        for (E l : ls) {
            res.add(f.apply(l));
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then, I call from main:

```
//Main.java
Foo<Integer> foo1 = new Foo<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
Foo<String> foo2 = foo1.map(a -> a.toString());
```

I want to see how defining the function as `Function<? super E, ? extends F>` gives an advantage over `Function<E,F>`? Is `Function<? super E, ? extends F>` for has the maximum flexibility? Could you please show it in a example by changing `Main.java`?

Comment: @knittl, unfortunately, it did not answer my question. My question is to find a case which `? super E, ? extends F` provide us more flexibility.  if it is clear to you could you please show it in the example? My example in `Main.java` can work with `Function<E, F>`.

Comment: I have not provided an answer, so I don't know what I didn't answer?

Comment: @knittl Somebody marked my question as duplicate and referred to the PECS article as the answer.  I assumed you have done it :)

Comment: @knittl do you know how can I get rid of the duplicate flag that people can answer my question?

Comment: Why does it not answer your question? [edit] the question to explain that and it might get re-opened. Simplified, a `Function<? super T, ? extends R>` can take a `animal -> new Tiger(animal.getName())` lambda, while `Function<T, R>` can not (because it can only be passed a `cat -> new Cat(cat.getName())`)

Comment: The answer was not correct. `Function<T, R>` can change any type to any other type. so, I assume `Function<T, R>`  can change cat to tiger as well.

Comment: `foo1.map((Number a) -> a.toString())` will not work with your given class if your type parameters are not co-/contravariant, because `Number` is not `Integer` (but `Integer implements Number`).

Comment: thank you. Your example can also run with `Function<? super E, F>`.  Could you please give an example which `? extends F` is also necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try to reason about generics with final classes like String and Integer.

Try a hierarchy like A > B > C

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

Then an example like

```
Foo<B> foo1 = new Foo<>(new B());
Function<A, C> aToC = a -> new C();
Foo<B> foo2 = foo1.map(aToC);
```

This won't work without both `super E` and `extends F`. The function takes an A - `foo1` is a B, but A is a super class of B - and returns a C - `foo2` is expecting a B, but C extends B.

If your `map` function were simply declared as

```
public <F> Foo<F> map(Function<E, F> f) {
```

then the above snippet wouldn't compile. The function would have to be `Function<B, B>`.

Hopefully that demonstrates why the more complex signature is more flexible.